# Add section in a nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap 3, i have a nav bar, with an form bar.

I try to add another section just to the right of the search button.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default pull-right">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inactiveLodger">Locataire inactif</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="lodgerSearch" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" id="username" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Paul Smith<b class="caret"></b></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> Changer mot de passe</a>
            </li>
            <li id="logout"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i>Déconnexion</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Righ now, the other section is below, like you can see on the image.

[image]

Comment: Is this all your using or is this part of a complete navbar? If theres more code please post it.

Comment: it's the complete nav bar... it's a search bar + user loged information

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `float:right` that is what `navbar-right` does, simply invert order of form and dropdown. right floated element must be placed BEFORE others in order to make others floats around them.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default pull-right">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" id="username" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Paul Smith<b class="caret"></b></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> Changer mot de passe</a>
            </li>
            <li id="logout"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i>Déconnexion</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inactiveLodger">Locataire inactif</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="lodgerSearch" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're applying other changes to the `navbar`, you shouldn't need the extra classes you've applied (col-sm-12/pull-right/etc). Just use the default classes and structure and but reorder your right floated navigation elements so they're in the order you want.

See example.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Paul Smith <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> Changer mot de passe</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i> Déconnexion</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" id="inactiveLodger">Locataire inactif</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button id="lodgerSearch" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>

              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```